# Is there Azure Storage library that works with .NETStandard 1.5?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to build .NET Core Class library that works with Azure Storage. Seems like the current version of WindowsAzure.Storage and it's dependencies require a full .net framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [change log for the storage client library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/changelog.txt), you need to use version 7.0.2 which is currently in preview. From the change log page:

> Changes in 7.0.2-preview :
>
> - Blobs (WinRT): Fixed a bug that caused DownloadToFile() to infinite loop for one overload.
> - All : **CoreCLR projects were updated to use the RC2 release of .Net Core 1.0**

You can download this version from Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/7.0.2-preview

Comment: actually, it doesn't work with netstandard1.5, only works with net451. It complains that the 4 dependent libraries (Microsoft.Data.Edm, odata, etc) don't support .NETStandard v1.5

Comment: Unfortunately I have not tried it myself. I just read the release notes and answered it. One thing you could do is raise this as a bug here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues or may be use some public forum like Twitter to ask this question. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

It works (and I've been using it) with version 7.0.2 preview ( as noted by @GauravMantri in previous answer).  You do need to make some adjustments to the imports section of the project.json.  Use this an example that works:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.0.2-preview"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```